# post google static map to facebook wall

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, google-maps

I want to post a google static map to facebook wall

this is [map url](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x315&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C23.597651,120.997932&markers=color:green%7Clabel:E%7C23.484676,121.022578&markers=color:red%7Clabel:T%7C25.2,122.5)

and open by chrome, is fine

but it wrong on facebook, I have three marker in this map

but just last one stay,as below
(the last marker is test if facebook just keep last one)

[image]

here is my code

```
NSString *staticMap = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x315&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue|label:S|%f,%f&markers=color:green|label:E|%f,%f&markers=color:red|label:T|25.2,122.5",dataManager.postCarpoolStartLat,dataManager.postCarpoolStartLng,dataManager.postCarpoolEndLat,dataManager.postCarpoolEndLng];

NSURL *staticMapURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[staticMap stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"static url : %@",staticMapURL);

if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"])
{
    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"message":@"this is test",
                             @"caption":@"this is caption",
                             @"description":@"description",
                             @"link":@"www.google.com",
                             @"name":@"Name",
                             @"picture":staticMapURL,
                             @"type":@"mobile",
                             };

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"post"];

    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error){

        if (!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"post success");
        }
    }];
}
```

Is anyone know how to let facebook show the right map?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you were able to find the solution on your own, you can post it as the answer and mark it as accepted so that anyone else who sees this question will know that it's resolved.

Comment: If what you want is to show a map on Facebook I would start by reading Custom Open Graph Stories (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom) so that you understand how people are achieving this right now